Can I make a button that reveals 2 more clickable buttons?
I've been going absolutely insane for the last 4h trying to learn. I'm so new to this pls help / be kind.
I'm making a website with VS Code. So, I want to make a button that when you click two more buttons appear - then each of them lead to different pages when clicked! I just can't figure out how.
It should be a button with this text:
Do you enter?
(click button. then these 2 buttons appear:)
YES     NO
I've tried to tinker with this one that I found online:
https://www.quora.com/How-can-a-button-reveal-another-button-when-hovered-over-using-CSS


.reveal-button {
  display: none;
  /* Initially hide the revealed button */
}

.main-button:hover+.reveal-button {
  display: inline block;
  /* Display the revealed button when main button is hovered */
}
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="main-button">Hover Me</button>
  <button class="reveal-button">Revealed Button</button>
</div>



But I can't find a way to make it be click instead of :hover even when I change to :focus. And with this method I can only make 1 button appear after the first, instead of 2.
Is my request impossible to make? Or am I just unaware of the answer?

Please update the question to include a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem you are trying to describe.

Additionally... The functionality you describe sounds like something one would write in JavaScript, but you appear to only be using HTML and CSS.  Perhaps the problem is that you need to write some JavaScript code and you simply haven't yet?

set hidden attribute on buttons and remove it w JS to show them. Use click event to remove.

You can achieve something similar to this, but I definitely think you need to use JavaScript for a more logical and efficient solution.


button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.button-hidden {
  display: none;
}
.main-button:hover ~ .hover-button {
  display: block;
}
.main-button:active ~ .active-button {
  display: block;
}
.main-button:focus ~ .focus-button {
  display: block;
}
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="main-button">Hover me, click & hold</button>
  <button class="button-hidden hover-button">Show on hover</button>
  <button class="button-hidden active-button">Show on active</button>
  <button class="button-hidden focus-button">Show on focus</button>
</div>



I suggest this solution to your answer:


// Select the elements
const mainButton = document.getElementById('main-button');
const responseButtons = document.getElementById('response-buttons');

// Add a click event listener to the main button
mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Show the hidden buttons and hide the main button
  responseButtons.classList.remove('hidden');
  mainButton.style.display = 'none';
});
.button {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<!-- Initial button -->
<button id="main-button" class="button">Do you enter?</button>

<!-- Hidden buttons -->
<div id="response-buttons" class="hidden">
  <a href="#url-if-yes" class="button">YES</a>
  <a href="#url-if-no" class="button">NO</a>
</div>




Try this method. Use JavaScript to change CSS:display of buttons.


let st=true;
function toggleDisplay(){
document.querySelectorAll('.toggleBTN').forEach(function(item){
if(st){item.style.display="inline-block";}
else{item.style.display="none";}
})
st=!st;
}

function gotoURL(strURL){
window.location.href = strURL; // possible to use the "back" button to previous page.
//window.location.replace(strURL); // is not possible to use the "back" button.
}
.toggleBTN{display:none;}
<button class="mainBTN" onclick="toggleDisplay();">click button</button>
<button class="toggleBTN" onclick="gotoURL('https://www.website1.com');">yes</button>
<button class="toggleBTN" onclick="gotoURL('https://www.website2.com');">no</button>




There are a couple of approaches using only HTML and CSS as follows, with explanatory comments in the code:


*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  block-size: 100dvb;
  padding: 1rem;
}

main {
  block-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

/* We're hiding the element visually with the opacity property,
   and preventing the element, and descendants, from appearing
   in the tab order while hidden: */
.choices {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* any .choices element that's a later sibling of a <label> element
   that has a checked <input> with a data-role attribute equal to
   "confirmation" will be styled to be visible (opacity: 1), and
   able to participate in the tab-order (visibility: visible): */
label:has(input[data-role="confirmation"]:checked) ~ .choices {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* the :popover-open pseudo-class styles popover elements
   that are currently displayed: */
div:popover-open {
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  inset: 50%;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin: auto;
}

/* styles the 'overlay' of the popover that reduces visibility
   of the underlying content: */
::backdrop {
  background: hsl(0deg 0% 0% / 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}
<!-- wrapping the page content  -->
<main>
  <!-- the 'container' elements are generic wrappers, and not required;
       though if you adjust the HTML structure - and therefore change
       the DOM - you may need to adjust the CSS selectors to reflect
       those changes: -->  
  <div class="confirmation-1">
    <!-- I habitually, mostly for styling reasons, wrap the text of a <label>
         element with a span, as follows, this is not required though: -->
    <label>
      <span class="labelText">Are you sure?</span>
      <!-- the custom data-role attribute is used in place of class,
           purely in order to easily select the element for use in the
           :has() pseudo-class: -->
      <input data-role="confirmation" type="checkbox" />
    </label>
    <!-- this element is hidden via CSS on page-load: -->
    <div class="choices">
      <!-- the various options, to be replaced with whatever you wish: -->
      <a href="#yes">Yes</a>
      <a href="#nope">No</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="confirmation-2">
    <!-- we're using the "popovertarget" attribute, with its value set to
    the 'id' of the element to be used as a popover: --> 
    <button popovertarget="verify">Are you sure?</button>
    <!-- the popover Boolean attribute (doesn't need a value, it only
         has to be present, or not) sets this element to act as a popover,
         note that the id is equal to the popovertarget of the <button>: -->
    <div popover id="verify">
      <a href="#yes">Yes</a>
      <a href="#nope">No</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>



References:

CSS:

backdrop-filter.
background.
block-size.
border.
border-radius.
box-sizing.
display.
gap.
:has().
inset.
margin.
opacity.
padding.
:popover-open.
transition.
visibility.


HTML:

Popover API.
popover attribute.
popovertarget attribute.




It is possible to make, you just had to push a little more.
The two button's container initially will be hidden and on click of 'Do you enter?' button it's style should be set of block/flex.


document.querySelector('.btn-enter').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.button-container').style.display = 'block';
});
.btn-enter {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-button:hover+.reveal-button {
  display: inline block;
}

.button-container {
  display: none;
}
<button class="btn-enter">Do you enter?</button>
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="main-button">Hover Me</button>
  <button class="reveal-button">Revealed Button</button>
</div>



